# java, ByteBuffer to parse data from file

Tags: java, bytebuffer

In java, I want to parse a file, with heterogenous data (numbers and characters), fast.

I've been reading about `ByteBuffer` and memory mapped files.

I can copy it, but when parsing data it becomes tricky. I'd like to do it allocating various bytes. But it become then dependent on the encoding?

If the format of the file is, for instance:

`someString 8

some other string 88`

How can I parse it to `String` or `Integer` objects?

Thanks!

Udo.

Comment: If sequentially accessed and reading "text" and "integers saved as text" is the primary use-case, then I would start with a *Buffered*Reader as a base. ByteBuffer is good for some things. This is generally not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your format is something like

```
{string possibly with spaces} {integer}\r?\n
```

You need to search for the newline, and work backward until you find the first space.  You can decode the number yourself and turn it into an `int` or turn it into a String and parse it.  I wouldn't use an Integer unless you had to.  Now you know where the start of the line is and the start of the integer you can extract the String as bytes and convert it into a String using your desired encoding.

This assumes that newline and space are one byte in your encoding. It would be more complicated if they are multi-byte byte it can still be done.

EDIT: The following example prints...

```
text: ' someString', number: 8
text: 'some other string', number: -88
```

Code

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(" someString 8\r\nsome other string -88\n".getBytes());
while(bb.remaining()>0) {
    int start = bb.position(),end, ptr;
    for(end = start;end < bb.limit();end++) {
        byte b = bb.get(end);
        if (b == '\r' || b == '\n')
            break;
    }
    // read the number backwards
    long value = 0;
    long tens = 1;
    for(ptr = end-1;ptr>= start;ptr--) {
        byte b = bb.get(ptr);
        if (b >= '0' && b <= '9') {
            value += tens * (b - '0');
            tens *= 10;
        } else if (b == '-') {
            value = -value;
            ptr--;
            break;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    // assume separator is a space....
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ptr-start];
    bb.get(bytes);
    String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("text: '"+text+"', number: "+value);

    // find the end of the line.
    if (bb.get(end) == '\r') end++;
    bb.position(end+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way:

```
CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(StringBuffer.toString());
for (char c = it.first(); c != CharacterIterator.DONE; c = it.next()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        // character is digit
    } else {
        // character is not-digit
    }
}
```

Or you can use regex if you prefer

```
String str = StringBuffer.toString();
String numbers = str.replaceAll("\\D", "");
String letters = str.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

Then you need to perform `Integer.parseInt()` as usual on the characters in your string `numbers`.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking  for a more specific ByteBuffer implementation.

Comment: A ByteBuffer giving `Strings` _and_ `Integers` based on some content?

Comment: What would `someString 8` return then? A string `someString` or an integer `8`?

Comment: well, just iterate, or some way to parse someString to a String object and 8 to an Integer.

Comment: Ah, like `o = buf.getNextSequence();` and `o instanceOf Integer` or `buf.isInt()`. Afraid the performance of such operations wouldn't necessarily be alot more perfomant since the character checks are only pushed down to the buffer implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`java.util.Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)? Unless you have really exotic performance requirements, that should be fast enough:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\test.txt"));
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String label = s.next();
        int number = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number + " " + label);
    }
```

Comment: Why? Have you verified the performance impact justifies the additional effort?

Comment: That's a good point, but I'm doing this just to learn how to  use it.